# How to get success callback on Intent.ActionSend

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin.android

In my Xamarin Android app, I've been working on creating an activity that will allow the user to share a file to another program (i.e. email, OneDrive, Google Drive, etc.). It's working, however it executes and returns immediately with a cancelled status. Then a nice menu opens asking the user which app to use, and ultimately saves the file successfully.

Is there anything that can be done to this activity to receive an OK status result when the user has finished selecting their file so my program knows success or cancellation?

My Activity:

```
public class FileShareActivity : Activity
{
    public static EventHandler<bool> Completed;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        string sourceFilePath = Intent.GetStringExtra("sourceFilePath");

        try {
            var file = new Java.IO.File(sourceFilePath);
            var fileUri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(Application.Context, fileProviderAuthority, file);
            if ( fileUri != null ) {
                var shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionSend);
                shareIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, fileUri);
                shareIntent.SetDataAndType(fileUri, Application.Context.ContentResolver.GetType(fileUri));
                shareIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
                shareIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

                StartActivityForResult(shareIntent, 0);
            }
        } catch ( Exception ex ) {
            Services.ExceptionService.Instance.HandleException(ex);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data) {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Completed?.Invoke(null, resultCode != Result.Canceled);
        Finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few more hours of research, I found the solution in the Android developer guides (at https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html).

> ...if you call Intent.createChooser(), passing it your Intent object, it returns a version of your intent that will always display [a] chooser.

So asynchrony can be achieved by changing the call to:

```
StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(shareIntent, "Share file"), 0)
```

The OnActivityResult override is executed after the chooser completes. While the resultCode still returns cancelled, the data parameter is null if the user cancelled out of the chooser and otherwise is an intent containing the name of the chooser used (**not** the name of the target app used). This can be used to determine chooser success by changing the line to

```
Completed?.Invoke(null, data != null)
```

Subscribers to the Completed event will be notified after the chooser process is completed, and a follow-up action can be executed.

The downside is that there is no way to determine if the user cancelled out of or completed the target operation with success, but that can be worked around.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anything that can be done to this activity to receive an OK status result when the user has finished selecting their file so my program knows success or cancellation?

No, there is nothing you can do in this activity to receive an OK status. Your app has successfully start the target app's activity, but the target app's activity didn't set result at all. So unless you can modify target app's codes, which is impossible, you will not get OK status.

And normally, we just use `StartActivity` together with `Intent.ActionSend`.